# TabNavigation/DrawerNavigation in a StackNavigation

Tags: react-native, exponentjs

I just can't figure it out how exactly I can have TabNavigation or DrawerNavigation inside StackNavigation (something like that):

[image]

So from the documentation if I have this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  createRouter,
  NavigationProvider,
  StackNavigation,
} from '@exponent/ex-navigation';

const Router = createRouter(() => ({
  home: () => HomeScreen,
}));

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationProvider router={Router}>
        <StackNavigation initialRoute={Router.getRoute('home')} />
      </NavigationProvider>
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static route = {
    navigationBar: {
      title: 'Home',
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flex: 1}}>
        <Text>HomeScreen!</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}


AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => App);
```

**Where I should apply/insert this snippet of code** again from documentation about adding Drawer/TabNavigation:

```
import {
  StackNavigation,
  DrawerNavigation,
  DrawerNavigationItem,
} from '@exponent/ex-navigation';

// Treat the DrawerNavigationLayout route like any other route -- you may want to set
// it as the intiial route for a top-level StackNavigation

class DrawerNavigationLayout extends React.Component {
  static route = {
    navigationBar: {
      visible: false,
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <DrawerNavigation
        id='main'
        initialItem='home'
        drawerWidth={300}
        renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
      >
        <DrawerNavigationItem
          id='home'
          selectedStyle={styles.selectedItemStyle}
          renderTitle={isSelected => this._renderTitle('Home', isSelected)}
        >
          <StackNavigation
            id='home'
            initialRoute={Router.getRoute('home')}
          />
        </DrawerNavigationItem>

        <DrawerNavigationItem
          id='about'
          selectedStyle={styles.selectedItemStyle}
          renderTitle={isSelected => this._renderTitle('About', isSelected)}
        >
          <StackNavigation
            id='about'
            initialRoute={Router.getRoute('about')}
          />
        </DrawerNavigationItem>

      </DrawerNavigation>
    );
  }

  _renderHeader = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.header}>
      </View>
    );
  };

  _renderTitle(text: string, isSelected: boolean) {
    return (
      <Text style={[styles.titleText, isSelected ? styles.selectedTitleText : {}]}>
        {text}
      </Text>
    );
  };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    height: 20
  },

  selectedItemStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue'
  },

  titleText: {
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },

  selectedTitleText: {
    color: 'white'
  }
});
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 0):

That's what I was looking for: https://github.com/sibelius/ex-navigation-drawer-tabs